# Making conditional statements with Shiny for functions and plotting

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app for a group of researchers to enable them to get a sense of their data prior to a more sophisticated data analysis. In some experiments they have a set of measurements (called 'phenotypes') for a group of replicates subjected to particular treatments. In other experiments, the experimental levels are a bit more complicated, where they are investigating the effect of a treatment and other experimental factors on the phenotype.

I would like to build an app that allows for flexibility of these different experimental structures, which would require conditional statements so that if an experimenter only cares about the effect of one treatment/factor level or more on the phenotype, that they can see basic statistics and descriptive statistics for that measurement. Right now, I have a shiny app written to force the experimenter to view their data if they select an item from each drop down column. Can someone please help with this??

In the dataset below, the experimenter may only care about the effect of 'N_level' or 'N_level' + 'Strain' or 'N_level' + 'Strain' + 'inoc_met'. In each of these three cases, I'd like them to see the basic statistics and also plot the descriptive stats plots for as simple or complex their experiment may be.

Some reproducible data is:

```
data <- structure(list(Strain = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NC", "t186673", 
"t186674", "t186675"), class = "factor"), N_level = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L), inoc_met = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DR", 
"ST"), class = "factor"), phenotype1 = c(40L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 
36L, 35L, 34L, 37L, 36L, 44L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 
44L, 35L, 42L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 38L, 42L, 35L, 45L, 
46L, 48L, 47L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 40L, NA, 37L, 39L, 40L, 38L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 43L, 50L, 40L, 41L, 40L, 44L, 50L, 46L, 35L, NA, 
34L, 36L, 42L, 37L, 37L, 34L, NA, 38L, 42L, 42L, 28L, 32L, 33L, 
43L, 44L, 44L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 33L, 37L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
42L, 38L, 42L, 40L, 44L, 45L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 47L, 
46L, 43L, 42L, 40L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 45L, 42L, 39L, 42L, 
35L, 37L, 34L, 38L, 43L, 45L, 33L, 36L, 35L, 46L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 
40L, 48L, 40L, 50L, 45L, 35L, 37L, 34L, 37L, 35L, 38L, 36L, 37L, 
35L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 35L, 32L, 33L, NA, 46L, 43L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code for the shiny App

```
library(shiny)
library(doBy)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Upload File"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Selection for the drop down menus given the colnames
      p("Select relevant columns from data for basic statistics"),
      uiOutput('phenotype'), 
      uiOutput('treatment'), 
      uiOutput('factor1'), 
      uiOutput('factor2'), 
      #uiOutput('factor3'),
      #
      selectInput("plot.type","Plot Type:",
                  list(boxplot = "boxplot", histogram = "histogram")
      ),
      checkboxInput("show.points", "show points", TRUE),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")



  ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      img(src = "joynLogo.jpeg", height = 150, width = 150),
      # Output: Data file ----
      p("View the head of your data"),
      tableOutput("contents"), # in order to view the header
      p("Take a look at your data overall, is all the information correct?"),
      verbatimTextOutput('summary'), # summary statistics for data frame as a whole
      p("Output basic statistics"),
      tableOutput('BasicStats'),
      h3(textOutput("caption")),
      p("Note that the figure below is made taking into consideration a single factor level"),
      uiOutput("plot")
    )
  )
  )


# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # print out the summary ----
  # define the dataset that you will get a summary output for 
    myData <- reactive({
              inFile <- input$file1
              if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
              data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
              data
  }) 



########## make a vector to output basic stats ###########  

    bs <- reactive({

      # Require all 4 input parameters be selected by the user
      req(input$phenotype, input$treatment, input$factor1, input$factor2)

      # Make a new data frame with the information needed to get the summary stats
      d <- data.frame(myData()[, input$phenotype], as.factor(myData()[, input$treatment]),
                      as.factor(myData()[, input$factor1]), as.factor(myData()[, input$factor2]))

      # Keep only non NA cases
      newDF <- as.data.frame(d[complete.cases(d),])

      # Rename columns
      colnames(newDF) <- c("x", "trt", "factor1", "factor2")

      # Extract summary stats
      result <- summaryBy( x ~ trt + factor1 + factor2, FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = newDF)
      result$x.se <- result$x.sd/sqrt(result$x.length)

      return(result)
    })

###################### Table output info #########################
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(myData())
    })

  output$BasicStats <- renderTable(bs())

############# Make Drop down menus of header contents##########      
  output$plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("p")
  })

  # This will switch what is printed in the caption of the figure
  output$caption<-renderText({
    switch(input$plot.type,
           "boxplot"    =   "Boxplot",
           "histogram" =    "Histogram")
  })

  output$phenotype <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("phenotype", "Phenotype:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$treatment <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("treatment", "Treatment:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor1 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor1", "Factor_1:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  output$factor2 <- renderUI({
    df <- myData()
    selectInput("factor2", "Factor_2:",c("",names(df)))
  })

  #output$factor3 <- renderUI({
  #  df <- myData()
   # selectInput("factor3", "Factor_3:",c("",names(df)))
 # })

 ######################### To view header ################################  
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

  ################################ Make figures ##############################
  output$p <- renderPlot({

    req(input$phenotype, input$treatment, input$factor1)

    #plot types
    plot.type<-switch(input$plot.type,
                      "boxplot"     = geom_boxplot(aes(stat="identity")),
                      "histogram" = geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,position="identity")
    )


    if(input$plot.type=="boxplot")  {       #control for 1D or 2D graphs
      p<-ggplot(myData(),
                aes_string(
                  x = input$treatment,
                  y = input$phenotype,
                  fill  = input$treatment
                ) # let type determine plotting
      ) + plot.type + labs(x = input$treatment, y = input$phenotype) + facet_grid(col = vars(myData()[,input$factor1]))
      #+ facet_grid(col = vars(myData()[,input$factor]), scales = "free")


      if(input$show.points==TRUE) # maybe do this for the factor level
      {
        p<-p+ geom_point(color='black',alpha=0.5, position = 'jitter')
      }

    } else {
      #   
      p<-ggplot(myData(),
                aes_string(
                  x         = input$phenotype,
                  fill  = input$treatment
                )
      ) + plot.type + labs(x = input$phenotype) + facet_grid(col = vars(myData()[,input$factor1]))

    }

    p<-p+ .theme
    print(p)
  })

  # set uploaded file
  upload_data<-reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    #could also store in a reactiveValues
    read.csv(inFile$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep)
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    inFile<<-upload_data()
  })

}
###########################################################################
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think you'll have to reduce the scope of your problem before getting a good answer. Try to consider what your smallest reproducible issue is and describe it here.